# Passing SQL Syntax parameter into R using glue::sql?

Tags: sql, r

I'm currently trying to create a temp table or a table or a View on the fly using glue::sql.

I understand and know how to build up a sql query using glue  by passing in R objects as parameters, however:

Is it possible to pass in an object that is converted into SQL syntax for creating a table?

for example my sql glue statement is the following:

```
sql_query <- glue::glue_sql(

    "create {create_type} some_table as
    select * from {`table_name`}

      where 
        ({`table_name`}._start_time >= {start}
        and

        {`table_name`}._end_time <= {end})
      or

        ({`table_name`}.type == 'internet'

       and
        {`table_name`}._start_time >= {start}

        and
        {`table_name`}.end_time <= {end} + 604800)



    ", 
    .con = conn
  )
```

I want to be able to pass a parameter such as `'TEMP TABLE' to {create_type}` so that it will be able to become: `"create TEMP TABLE some_table as...."`

I have not seen any examples where this has been done, so wondered if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a good work around is to create an object before hand using `paste()`

```
test <- "TEMP TABLE"

create_sql_line <-paste("create", test) 

    sql_query <- glue::glue_sql(
    create_sql_line,
        " some_table as
        select * from {`table_name`}

          where 
            ({`table_name`}._start_time >= {start}
            and

            {`table_name`}._end_time <= {end})
          or

            ({`table_name`}.type == 'internet'

           and
            {`table_name`}._start_time >= {start}

            and
            {`table_name`}.end_time <= {end} + 604800)



        ", 
        .con = conn
      )
```

As you pass in the object into glue_sql that is created above.

Works well and creates SQL syntax perfectly!